# Using a concatenated string in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, string, string-concatenation

Thought I was being clever by concatenating my values and field names from an array and then inserting them into the SQL. This was aimed to save me putting loads of values directly into my function im using.

So I have an array which I loop through and concatenate the values to make a string.

```
foreach ($customer_info as $key=>$value) {
    $fieldInsert .= '`'.$key.'`,';
    $valueInsert .= $value.',';
}

$fieldInsert = rtrim($fieldInsert, ",");
$valueInsert = rtrim($valueInsert, ",");
```

This correctly creates two strings e.g.:

```
`field1`,`field2`,`field3`
value1,value2,value3
```

I then have my query:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `customers` ('$fieldInsert') VALUES ('$valueInsert')");
var_dump($query);
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Just trying to set up error handling as we speak since working on someone elses project.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). What you're doing here is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work in mySql but I do know SQL well.  The issue is you cannot use variables for object names in a query unless you build an entire string and pass it to the an execution command. I will show you an example in t-SQL which is my native language.

You will notice I create two tables and put data in them.  They have different column and table names but the SQL statement that selects from them uses variables to concatenate into a reusable statement.  Once the statement is constructed I pass it to the EXECUTE command.  I believe in mySql the command is EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but I'm not sure.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.tables where name = 'People')
DROP TABLE People
GO
-- First create one table with a list of people
CREATE TABLE People(
PersonId INT NOT NULL,
FirstName VARCHAR(20) NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(20) NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO People (PersonId, FirstName, LastName) VALUES 
(1, 'George', 'Washington'),
(2, 'Thomas', 'Jefferson'),
(3, 'Teddy', 'Roosevelt'),
(4, 'Abe', 'Lincoln')
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.tables where name = 'RushmoreHeads')
DROP TABLE RushmoreHeads
GO

-- Then create one table with a list of the heads on Mount Rushmore
CREATE TABLE RushmoreHeads(
RushId INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(30) NULL,
PresidentNumber INT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO RushmoreHeads(RushId, Name, PresidentNumber ) VALUES 
(1, 'George Washington', 3),
(2, 'Thomas Jefferson', 2),
(3, 'Teddy Roosevelt', 26),
(4, 'Abe Lincoln', 16)
GO

DECLARE @SQLPrefix VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQLDelimiter VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQLSuffix VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQLWhere VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Column1 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Column2 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Column3 VARCHAR(20)

DECLARE @SQL2Execute VARCHAR(2000)

SET @SQLPrefix = 'SELECT '
SET @SQLSuffix = ' FROM '
SET @SQLDelimiter = ' , '

-- Object names from first table
SET @Table = 'People'
SET @Column1 = 'PersonId'
SET @Column2 = 'FirstName'
SET @Column3 = 'LastName'

-- Construct the select statement
SET @SQL2Execute = @SQLPrefix + @Column1+ @SQLDelimiter + 
    @Column2+ @SQLDelimiter + @Column3+ @SQLSuffix + @Table
PRINT @SQL2Execute

EXECUTE (@SQL2Execute)

-- Object names from second table
SET @Table = 'RushmoreHeads'
SET @Column1 = 'RushId'
SET @Column2 = 'Name'
SET @Column3 = 'PresidentNumber'

-- Same code as first table
SET @SQL2Execute = @SQLPrefix + @Column1+ @SQLDelimiter + 
    @Column2+ @SQLDelimiter + @Column3+ @SQLSuffix + @Table

EXECUTE (@SQL2Execute)
PRINT @SQL2Execute
```